# Installing a fake microphone on Windows Server

Tags: audio, skype, microphone, windows-server

My application, that is running on Windows Server (which is an instance on Amazon EC2) requires Skype to be able to make phone calls. The server, of course, does not have a microphone installed and I don't need it to have one, because my application changes the input source to a wav file when the call is established. However, Skype has a strict rule that a microphone must be installed for a call to be made.

Thus I want to install a fake microphone that will trick Skype's configuration.

So far, I was able to start and run the Windows Sound service, which enabled all of the sound settings.

Any ideas are very welcome!

Answer (score 3):

[Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.html) should do what you need, including redirecting the playback of your wav file from a virtual speaker to your virtual microphone if desired:
http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.html

<s>Microsoft publishes the source code for a [Virtual Audio Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff537517(v=VS.85).aspx) as part of the [Windows Driver Development Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/WDK/default.mspx).  If you have access to Visual Studio, or if you know a programmer who does, compiling this virtual driver and installing it on your EC2 instance may accomplish what you need.</s>

Comment: Dead link for the VAD.

Comment: Shoot. I wonder if they migrated it to GitHub? https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/audio/sysvad

Comment: From user [vichar](https://superuser.com/users/950212/vichar): The virtual audio cable software worked for me on AWS EC2 instance.   From myself, it isn't clear why that solution is crossed out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. It has it's limitations like :
"Local session only (not available from Remote Desktop)"
"The trial is 100% functional, but you get an annoying message every few seconds saying it's a trial."

http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.html

Comment: If it can't be used from Remote Desktop, how is it useful for an EC2 instance?

Comment: @Miles Erickson - don't mean to be a PITA, but if this is a restriction, it is the same software you recommended in your answer!

Comment: @Wil Crap, you're right.  That's pretty funny.  I'll have to revise my answer.

Comment: (It has been confirmed to work on remote servers.)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to install a random driver for any microphone. There should be a standard microsoft driver implemented in Windows. I don't know if Skype checks for a real physical microphone but I guess it's just searching for an installed driver.

Answer (score -1):

Can you install a microphone and then either not use it or disable it? Since you're changing the input to a .wav, it won't really matter.

I know it seems wasteful, put it might be the easiest solution.

Comment: His server is running in the "cloud" using Amazon EC2.  Thus he has no access to install a physical microphone.

Comment: good and IMPORTANT point.